# Access personal geodatabase using Java

Tags: arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, java, personal-geodatabase

Following [example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-java/concepts/engine/index.html#/Access_file_geodatabase/00010000061v000000) through ESRI is to access the features of file geodatabase (GDB), I would like to know that is there a similar way to do this with personal geodatabase (MDB) using Java.

I am quite new to ArcObjects so if anybody could point me to right direction.

Comment: Are you wedded to Personal Geodatabases rather than File Geodatabases?  There is a [**Q & A**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60196/should-i-use-file-geodatabase-gdb-personal-geodatabase-mdb-or-shapefile) available about their relative virtues.

Comment: Its not like "WEDDED", its just a tool generation to handle both geodatabase , so no PRO CONS .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`AccessWorkspaceFactory`](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/sdk/10.0/Java_AO_ADF/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/datasourcesGDB/AccessWorkspaceFactory.html) instead. There are (at least) 3 ways to connect to a personal geodatabase. The simplest is probably the [`IWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geodatabase/IWorkspaceFactory.html#openFromFile%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method, e.g.:

```
//For example, pathToFile= "C:\\myData\\mypGDB.mdb".
static IWorkspace openFromFile_pGDB_Workspace(String pathToFile)throws Exception{
    IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new AccessWorkspaceFactory();
    return workspaceFactory.openFromFile(pathToFile, 0);
}
```

See [How to connect to a geodatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualHelp/engine/index.html#Access) in the conceptual help for more information.

You might also look at the various [`IGPUtilities`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geoprocessing/IGPUtilities.html) helper methods if you want to deal with opening workspaces, feature classes, tables, etc. in a more generic way.