# How to speed up redrawing of layers (from shapefiles) in MXD?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, performance, display

How do I speed up the process of redrawing layers in a MXD?

I have already tried reloading and indexing the layers.

The layers were created from shapefiles.

Comment: are you in a database of any kind right now? or are you strictly calling shapefiles into your mxd?

Comment: For discussion on shapefiles versus databases, please read [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60196/whether-to-use-file-geodatabase-gdb-personal-geodatabase-mdb-or-shapefi).

Comment: Clear your cache and see improving speeds "You'll need to devise a strategy to manage how your local cache is managed, either layer by layer or for all the contents in your display cache." http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000180000000

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to edit or change symbology in your layers (too often), you can use [Basemap layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000017000000). It will keep the data in-memory after drawing it for the first time.

But, as mentioned, the price to pay is that the only thing you can do with a layer in a Basemap layer group is turn it on or off. Everything else is disabled.

Another thing you can do is to save all your data on disk instead of a remote server, if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 1):

Some points to improve display performance of vector data:

**Data**

- use File Geodatabase instead of Shape Files
- use [Basemap layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000017000000)
- avoid projection on-the-fly
- Generalize data ([Generalize Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Generalize/001v00000006000000/), [Integrate Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000)  )

**Layer**

- [set visible scale range](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/na/00s500000008000000/) to display layers only at certain scales
- use [definition queries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Displaying_a_subset_of_features_in_a_layer/00s50000002z000000/) to display only a subset of features in a layer

**Symbols/Styles**

General:

- Use simple cartographic symbols/styles.
- Use only one symbol layer to create your symbol. Symbols created of multiple layers decrease performance.

for points:

- Use simple or character marker symbols.
- Do not use picture marker symbols.
- If you can’t avoid picture marker symbols then use wmf. Do not use bmp.
- Don’t use a “mask”.

For lines:

- Use simple solid lines.
- Marker, cartographic Lines, offset and others will decrease performance

For polygons:

- Use simple fill with simple outline.
- Fill marker, picture fill, character marker fill and others will decrease performance

**Label/Annotation**

- Turn labeling off.
- use display range for labels and annotations
- Use label classes to display only a subset of features with Labels.
- Using of label weight will decrease Performance
- Label expressions decrease performance
- Annotations are faster than labels
- Store annotations in Geodatabases, not in MXD

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the use of a file geodatabase. This clearly improves the speed at which the layers are drawn.