# Projecting GeoJSON polygon object in python to calculate area

Tags: python, coordinate-system, area, shapely

I have a script, written in python, that does many calculations - but one set of calculations hinges on determining the area of a polygon that I read in, in GeoJSON format. I can convert this object to a shaply object (package), a WKT object, a dictionary, etc., none of allows me to directly determine the projected area.  Converting to a shapely object allows me to know the GCS area, but shapely doesn't have tools for projecting objects. Is there a package or module to project this object in python, using the arguments I supply (the GCS it's in, the PCS I hope to project it to) so that I can determine the area?

Comment: Doing a quick search here using http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projection-conversions+python seems to throw up several candidates: proj.4, pyproj and gdal - have you tried any of them?

Comment: I have not been able to get gdal to install, and am struggling with pyproj right now....but i may get it, so you can put this on hold if you feel its necessary.

Comment: @traggatmot the Shapely manual has a section on projecting objects: http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#other-transformations.

Comment: @sgillies, hey!  Great package!  I indeed got it figured out (though the area calc isn't shown, I got it working): http://stackoverflow.com/q/34325030/1762492

Comment: This was a fine question @PolyGeo and I'm disputing your hold. The question is less general than the one at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60196/whether-to-use-file-geodatabase-gdb-personal-geodatabase-mdb-or-shapefi/60198#60198 for sure.

Comment: @sgillies I only voted to close this after the asker had suggested I do so, and I assumed they were intending to revise it later, so On Hold seemed appropriate.  I just reviewed the other question you referenced and converted it to Community Wiki with a Wiki Lock because I agree that it is too broad.

Comment: So, I now know how to answer this myself....I guess I will in the next day or two unless someone else wants to.