# Getting around current database field limitations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, csv, ms-access

I have a need to store over 350 fields in a table and have this information readily available to display spatially. The problem is that access only allows for 255 fields. So the feature class that I am wanting to store all of this information does not have the ability to hold all of those fields..

Can you help me think of ways around this limit?

The only solution I can think of is to store all of my information in a big, long csv and then call out the information that I want at that time in a join.

The office that I am at is behind on the times and is still heavily using Access to query and store our data. We are WELL AWARE of the limitations and are on our way sometime in the next year to hopefully go to ArcGIS for Server and SQL server.

Comment: You already have a [tag:file-geodatabase] tag - that would seem to be a solution to your stated problem of too many fields.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand how a file-geodatabase can solve my problem?

Comment: Perhaps review http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/60196/115

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personal geodatabases--really anything with Access--have a ton of limitations. [File geodatabases](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabase-size-and-name-limits.htm) permit up to 65,534 fields per table/feature class.

It should be no problem to [import](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-importing-datasets.htm) your existing data to a file geodatabase and then make the changes/additions that you need.