# Edited metadata disappears in ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, arccatalog, personal-geodatabase

I'm quite new to GIS (being a student) and I have to edit the metadata for a couple of layers in my personal geodatabase. The problem I have is when I'm editing the metadata for the rasters it keeps disappearing after I click save. It looks good first (I edit all under the item description tab such as title purpose etc). Then as soon as I've saved and I click on another dataset and go back to my freshly edited raster it's all gone. Nothing is saved.

When I edited the metadata for the vector layers it worked just fine and it's saved and still there. The metadata template I'm using is FGDC CSDGM.  Do any of you know whats going on? Have I done something wrong with my rasters? Or is there something wrong with ArcCatalog?

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue before. You can edit metadata from one of 3 routes: Arcatalog, Catalog window in ArcMap or from the layer loaded in the TOC in Arcmap. Regardless of which route you take it does not stay after you press save.

This problem is discussed on the geonet website several years ago and a quick search on the current esri bug list shows it was [still around](http://support.esri.com/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4NDg0Mw==) in 2015.

Their solution is to have the raster in a file geodatabase instead of a personal geodatabase.

Comment: On the topic of storage types: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60196/whether-to-use-file-geodatabase-gdb-personal-geodatabase-mdb-or-shapefi

Comment: Thank you very much. Using the file geodatabase instead resolved the issue.

Comment: I just ran into this issue in arcCatalogue 10.8.1 - used the same solution, import the raster into a file geodatabase.